# Linear Regression in R, p value for coefficients different than 1

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

The default OLS regression in R gives me the p-value regarding whether or not the coefficient is different from zero.
Is there a way to change this default regarding coefficients that are different from one?

Thank you

Comment: just do a linear hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just carry out the linear hypothesis. In R use the function `car::LinearHypothesis`:

```
mod <- lm(Sepal.Width~., iris)
```

then run any of the following to test as to whether the coefficient for `Petal.Length = 1`

```
car::linearHypothesis(mod, "Petal.Length = 1")
car::lht(mod, "Petal.Length = 1")

Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
Petal.Length = 1

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1    145 24.837                                  
2    144 10.328  1    14.509 202.31 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```